# XML declaration error when trying to read an excel worksheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel, xml

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath + exportFileName))
{
    using (ExcelPackage xlPack = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(importFile)))
    {
        /*var xmlDec = xlPack.Workbook.WorkbookXml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);

        var root = xlPack.Workbook.WorkbookXml;

        root.RemoveChild(root.FirstChild);

        root.PrependChild(xmlDec);*/

        //xlPack.Workbook.WorkbookXml.InsertBefore(xmlDec, root.ParentNode);

        var worksheets = xlPack.Workbook.Worksheets;
```

xml sample --> `<workbook xmlns:r=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships xmlns=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main>`

Error occurs on the last line where I am trying to assign worksheets to a variable.

Error message is:

> Additional information: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 1672.

I have tried removing the declaration and creating a new one and then prepending. The error message is exactly the same. I'm not really familiar with xml encoding and especially with excel worksheets.

Comment: Likely we need to see a sample of the raw XML to help you.  Can you [edit] your question to share a sample?  Also, are you using [tag:epplus] to read the file?

Comment: I added a sample from the workbook xml, I'm not entirely sure which xml it would be. I unzipped the xlsx and this one seems to be the one that would match what I need? I'm currently using openofficexml

Comment: That's just the beginning of the XML, right?  What happens if you copy/paste all of it into an XML validator such as https://www.xmlvalidation.com/, is it OK?  Maybe when the file was saved, somebody added some extra XML to the end of the workbook package part, rendering it invalid?

Comment: Correct, that was just the beginning. I pasted the entire piece into xmlvalidation.com and it's reporting back with no errors found

Comment: Could there be a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning?  A [proper XML parser](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding) should handle a BOM but maybe the one you are using does not.  And if not, any chance you could share a [mcve] somehow?

Comment: So I opened the xml file inside notepad++ and it looks like it's UTF-16 LE BOM. My question is is there a way to do change this without all the manual leg work? I see it that encoding can be changed by selecting encoding on the menu but this is not feasible for the amount of files I will have.

Comment: Is the BOM incorrect?  Or is the XML actually encoded in UTF-16 LE?  What happens if you remove it manually and paste the XML back into the xlsx file, does the problem resolve itself?  And can the file be opened in Excel itself, without warnings?

Comment: Open XML is not Microsoft Excel.  I've never been able to use Open XML with Excel.  You are failing because the Excel document does not meet the OpenXML schema.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm not following.  Modern Excel documents are just OpenXML documents.  Yeah, there was a transitional format as the standard firmed up, but an XLSX file is an OpenXML file

Comment: @Flydog57 : Really?  I do not think so.

Comment: Yes, really. It's aka ISO/ IEC-29500. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML. All the modern Office file formats are based on the OpenXML formats. You can use the OpenXML SDK to parse or create Excel, Word and PowerPoint files. I've done it several times